# CentOS 8 Boot ISO asks for login?

Tags: centos, login

The GUI of Cent OS installer makes the server freeze for some reason, so I'm trying to install it from command line. (persistant across # images & medias)

I've appended the following to the kernel boot options to enable it :
systemd.unit=multi-user.target

Get prompted with a localhost login & password, did some research, none of the default credentials found on previous versions seems to work for this one

root/12qwaszx - root/'' - root/centos (...)

Anybody knows how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what your question is, or whether you are trying to install CentOS from a USB created from the boot ISO, or just run it from a USB created from the boot ISO.

The root password on the boot ISO seems to be null (that's what I see in /etc/shadow after booting from the boot image and dropping into a single-user shell), so I am not sure why it is not letting you log in as root with no password - there may be something used by the login process that is just not available on the filesystem provided by the boot ISO.

If you're actually trying to install CentOS to hard disk, set the kernel option `inst.text` to install in text mode, as described [here](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Text_Installation_Intro-x86/).

If you are not trying to install CentOS to hard disk and you just want to run it from the bootable USB, you could boot the bootable USB with the boot option `rd.break` which will drop you into a single-user shell (with the installation repo mounted at /run/install/repo), and then you can do whatever you want, within the bounds of whatever is available on the filesystem that's provided in the boot image.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's a boot iso flashed in USB.

Comment: The inst.text option does work but i was looking to install it from command line not just a text mode translation of the GUI, hence the systemd option. Do you know a way to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure how one with install from the command line (rather than the text-based installer), other than doing all of the operations that the installer would do, by hand.  And I'm not sure why it's not letting you log in as root - I just tried this, I get the same result, but in /etc/shadow, root's password is null (and it/s null in /sysroot/etc/passwd, too, in case that's what's being used).  Be that as it may - if you boot with kernel option `rd.break`, you'll get dropped into a single-user shell with the install CD mounted at /run/install/repo, and then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: I got the clue about the `rd.break` option from: https://www.linuxtechi.com/boot-centos-8-rhel-8-single-user-mode/

Comment: Anaconda (the CentOS installer) has its own systemd target. I imagine that there is no way to log in at multiuser.target, since it wasn’t intended to be used that way. There is no “command line” installer other than the text mode.

Comment: I'm currently trying to install it from a root console, it seems that most commands needed for partitioning, chrooting and setting up grub are available.

Comment: I don't know if what i'm doing is right probably not, but that's the only choice i'm left with, text mode also gets stuck in the [3] Installation source option

Comment: I hope you can make it work, though from your description, this sounds more like a hardware issue than a problem with the installers.  I've seen the RHEL/CentOS/Fedora GUI installers have problems in the past, for example when using very old graphics cards.  But if the text mode installer is hanging too, in the same place, that would make me suspect there's either a hardware problem or incompatibility with your system, or possibly some kind of issue with the specific USB flash drive you're using.

Comment: Once in the text console, it is just a tmux session, so you can run `control-b c` and get a new shell with a limited set of commands.  You can use that to partition disks and the n tell the kernel to re-evaluate the disks.